# iPhone error ld: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, json, cordova

I am try to create Phonegap project in which i need to integrate `ASIHTTPRequest` and JASON in reference,

and got following error

> ld: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in
>   /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap and
>   /Users/Alliancetek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloPhoneGap1-dwnmrmnkqwhiuoaagvbogktdnmlb/Build/Intermediates/HelloPhoneGap1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloPhoneGap1.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase.o for architecture i386 Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have duplicate symbols for SBJSON. You are probably linking to a static library that has the compiled SBJSON sources in it, if you are also compiling SBJSON this could lead to this problem. Try removing the SBJSON implementation files from your Compile Sources build phase.

Comment: Thank you!! Had a similar problem with PhoneGap Facebook iOS plugin and Facebook SDK 3.5,